# Remove text containing specific character in variable with windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, command

I wish to remove the text containing equal sign in my environment variable,
my code snippet as below:

```
SET JAVA_OPTS= -Dlog4j.configuration=./logservice.properties -Duser.timezone=GMT+08:00
SET "logText= -Dlog4j.configuration=./logservice.properties "
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo JAVA_OPTS = %JAVA_OPTS%
SET "JAVA_OPTS=!JAVA_OPTS:%logText%= !"
@echo modified JAVA_OPTS = !JAVA_OPTS!
ENDLOCAL & SET "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%"
```

The expected output after text removal should be

```
modified JAVA_OPTS = -Duser.timezone=GMT+08:00
```

How can I achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET JAVA_OPTS= -Dlog4j.configuration=./logservice.properties -Duser.timezone=GMT+08:00
SET "logText1= -Dlog4j.configuration"
SET "logText2=./logservice.properties "
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
echo JAVA_OPTS = %JAVA_OPTS%
SET "JAVA_OPTS=!JAVA_OPTS:*%logText1%=!"
SET "JAVA_OPTS=!JAVA_OPTS:*%logText2%=!"
echo modified JAVA_OPTS = !JAVA_OPTS!
ENDLOCAL & SET "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%"
echo final JAVA_OPTS = %JAVA_OPTS%
ENDLOCAL
:: have now backed out environment variable updates - try again
SETLOCAL
SET JAVA_OPTS= -Dlog4j.configuration=./logservice.properties -Duser.timezone=GMT+08:00
SET "logText2=./logservice.properties "
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
echo JAVA_OPTS = %JAVA_OPTS%
SET "JAVA_OPTS=!JAVA_OPTS:*%logText2%=!"
echo modified JAVA_OPTS = !JAVA_OPTS!
ENDLOCAL & SET "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%"
echo final JAVA_OPTS = %JAVA_OPTS%

GOTO :EOF
```

Two ways. You pays your money, you takes your choice.

The problem centres around the special use of `=` which `cmd` can't distinguish. Which string is the replacement?

Comment: Ah...wildcard, simply need to remove the text with **=** and replace with empty string. Thanks for your help!